# How to switch/update viewcontroller using one one Viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, collectionview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEQNw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH29f.png)

let's say I have 6 different viewControllers with different contents inside it, and one mainViewController. And MainViewcontroller contains a collectionView iside it, and when one of its cells are selected, I would like to have another stand alone ViewController which handles the update and switch function to the corresponding (6 different Controllers, in this case) viewControllers.. I have implemented the storyBoard showSegue method so far, it is however working , but i think it is not clean and the most right way since storyBoard seagues look a bit messy with this method, Can anyone explain or guide me through this, how to go about it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should avoid putting many view controllers in one storyboard. I prefer using the Coordinator pattern. Here is an example: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/71/how-to-use-the-coordinator-pattern-in-ios-apps

In my projects I use one Storyboard per ViewController and I have a coordinator that I can access from anywhere in the app. It makes your code super flexible. Give it a try...

Comment: is it possible to implement the same concept for separate viewControllers or does it always need to start from the root Controller? Because I already have the root controller and would be better if they would not interfere each other.. .

Comment: @ Nico S. could you suggest any idea for this?

Comment: You can start your coordinator (that handle all logic related to viewController appearing) in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of `AppDelegate` class.  Coordinator can start with `start(window: UIWindow)` method that will present the first viewController in a way like that: `self.window.rootViewController = viewController`